# filename on server Ã¼ instead of ü

Tags: unicode, filenames

I have a strange issue with a filename. But I am not sure if it is an issue from the server or so:

The link I have on the website is follow:

> [http://new.anwaltskanzlei-hauser.ch/rechtsberatung_zürich.php?lang=ge](http://new.anwaltskanzlei-hauser.ch/rechtsberatung_z%C3%BCrich.php?lang=ge)

Or, if I copy and paste into here:

> http://new.anwaltskanzlei-hauser.ch/rechtsberatung_z%C3%BCrich.php?lang=ge

The filename on the server is: rechtsberatung_zÃ¼rich.php .

So, I do not know, what exactly I need to change, that I have a filename called `rechtsberatung_zürich.php`

I know it is an issue with the charset and so on. Any help?

Comment: "enter link description here"?

Comment: Somebody fumbled a utf-8 encoded string.  That might not necessarily be you, but is the first place you look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the page looks fine from the outside I don't think you need to change anything on the server.

> The filename on the server is: rechtsberatung_zÃ¼rich.php .

Sounds like you are using a file transfer tool that treats the server's filesystem as being in the `windows-1252` encoding, when actually the server treats it as being UTF-8.

How exactly you change the encoding that your file transfer tool assumes for remote filesystems varies depending on what the tool is. For example with WinSCP there is the [UTF-8 Encoding for Filenames](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_environment#utf) option.

(If you are using the support for FTP built-in to Explorer then there's nothing you can do, it always uses your local machine's default locale encoding, which is never UTF-8, unfortunately. But you don't want to be using FTP in this century, you should try to move to SFTP in any case.)

Answer (score 0):

you can format charset if it is in a db as comparision 'utf8_general_ci' language options

Comment: It look a bit strange for me. If I have the filename as rechtsberatung_zÃ¼rich.php it works fine. If I have the filename as rechtsberatung_zürich.php it not works.

In the database I have allready utf8-general-ci.

What and where can I check more?

Kindly Simon

Answer (score 0):

I would just do a site wide unicode cleanup, read directories, glob directories, read file paths, file name, and files, and convert everything to use a single character set, preferably utf-8 or utf-32, then use that character set for everything, server, db, scripting, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do a site wide unicode cleanup, read directories, glob directories, read file paths, file name, and files, and convert everything to use a single character set, preferably utf-8 or utf-32, then use that character set for everything, server, db, scripting, etc, etc, and you can use the PHP mb_ function set to do all that.

```
<?php

function fixEncoding ( $string, $e_f, $e_t )
{
    return mb_convert_encoding ( $string, $e_f, $e_t );
}

$string = "Italienische GemÃ¼sesuppe";

$encode_from = "windows-1252";

$encode_to = "UTF-8";

echo fixEncoding ( $string, $encode_from, $encode_to ) . "\r\n";

?>
```

Answer (score -4):

Its a problem with UTF-8 charset, it doesnt support some lation characters. Probably you should use ISO-8859-1 charset encoding in place of UTF-8.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly the opposite of the truth. UTF-8 encoding supports **all** Unicode characters, which, yes, does mean every character in every Latin charset anyone ever came up with. That doesn't mean it uses the same byte sequence for all of them, though.

Comment: Sorry, this is just *utter nonsense*. UTF-8 supports all of Unicode, including the Latin-1 (ISO-8858-1) block. UTF-8 encodes codepoints outside of the ASCII range (so anything higher than U+007F) to two bytes or more, instead. The problem here is that the UTF-8 data is not being decoded as UTF-8, but using a Latin codec (not Latin-1, but Windows codepage 1252).